# Using wp_mail() instead of mail() in Wordpress does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Since PHP mail has been disabled on my server it has stopped a theme integrated contact form from working.

The theme is called Boldy and it has its own sendmail.php file which uses `mail()` instead of `wp_mail()`.

Changing `mail()` to `wp_mail()` does not work, but I'm not sure why?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    error_reporting(E_NOTICE);

    function valid_email($str)
    {
        return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    if ($_POST['name'] != '' && $_POST['email'] != '' && valid_email($_POST['email']) == TRUE && strlen($_POST['comment']) > 1)
    {
        $to = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $_POST['receiver']);
        $from = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $_POST['email']);
        $subject = "Website contact message from ".$_POST['name'];
        $message = $_POST['comment'];
        $match = "/(bcc:|cc:|content\-type:)/i";

        if (preg_match($match, $to) || preg_match($match, $from) || preg_match($match, $message))
        {
            die("Header injection detected.");
        }

        $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-to: ".$from."\r\n";

        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
        {
            echo 1; //SUCCESS
        }
        else
        {
            echo 2; //FAILURE - server failure
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 3; //FAILURE - not valid email
    }

}
else
{
    die("Direct access not allowed!");
}
?>
```

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm running into the exact same issue right now for my site...Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Insert at line 2:

```
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('../../../wp-load.php');
```

The trick is that sendmail.php as originally written doesn't actually load in the wordpress gear, so wp_mail isn't defined.

The first line should be optional. I took it from the sample code at http://butlerblog.com/2012/09/23/testing-the-wp_mail-function/.

Comment: I get a error 500 on the whole website when I put that code in my functions.php file (that is used to send email), not sure if the ../.. is the right number of levels or what

Answer (score 1):

I've lost about 30 minutes figuring this out.

If you're using anything that allows you to configure SMTP within WordPress, take it out.

Then put everything into a function:

```
add_action('init','delay_until_init');
function delay_until_init(){
   // call wp_mail() here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Wordpress function `wp_mail()` uses PHPs internal `mail()` function so the change you've made won't fix the issue.

If your web server has disabled the standard PHP `mail()` function then you will need to switch over to using SMTP for sending your emails.

There's a few different ways to achieve this, but the easiest method I've found has been to use the [Easy WP SMTP plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/). Once installed, you'll need to configure the plugin to use the login details for your SMTP server. If you hvae a Gmail address, you can use those details for setting it up.

EDIT: You still need to switch your code over to using the `wp_mail()` function which will automatically use SMTP (if you have the WP SMTP plugin installed).

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, because wp_mail() also has similair server requirements, which can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail